# How to setup "ResetOnLogon" different for each session?

Tags: fix-protocol, quickfixj

I'm implementing app for integration over Fix protocol using QuickFixJ lib.

There will be two sessions with service provider. First needs `ResetOnLogon=Y` and second `ResetOnLogon=N`.

I tried this config:

```
[default]
FileStorePath=target/data/barxfx
BeginString=FIX.4.2
ConnectionType=initiator
SocketConnectHost=123.123.123.123
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=00:00:00
HeartBtInt=120
ReconnectInterval=120
TimeStampPrecision=SECONDS

[session]
SenderCompID=A-PRICES-TEST
TargetCompID=B-PRICES-TEST
SocketConnectPort=62345
ResetOnLogon=Y
ResetOnDisconnect=Y

[session]
SenderCompID=A-TRADES-TEST
TargetCompID=B-TRADES-TEST
SocketConnectPort=62346
ResetOnLogon=N
ResetOnDisconnect=N
```

Init code:

```java
 InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/testfix.cfg");

SessionSettings settings = new SessionSettings(inputStream);
inputStream.close();

Application application = new QuickFixApplication();

MessageStoreFactory messageStoreFactory = new FileStoreFactory(settings);

LogFactory logFactory = new SLF4JLogFactory(settings);

MessageFactory messageFactory = new quickfix.fix42.MessageFactory();

SocketInitiator initiator = new SocketInitiator(application, messageStoreFactory, settings, logFactory, messageFactory);
initiator.start();
```

But it won't work - as `ResetOnLogon` is being overwritten by the last session on the list and this setting is being used for two sessions.

Any ideas how to customize `ResetOnLogon` per session?

Comment: This should definitely work per session, otherwise it is a bug. Which version of QuickFIX/J are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 2.1.1.

Comment: Can you share some code? How are you passing the settings to your application?

Comment: Sure. I've just updated my post :)

Comment: How can I show all settings used in sessions during runtime?

Comment: IIRC you can only do that via JMX. So you need to start jconsole and attach to your process. That will also show the settings of the various sessions. But this only works if you export an MBean. See here: https://www.quickfixj.org/usermanual/2.1.0/usage/jmx.html and here https://www.quickfixj.org/usermanual/2.1.0/usage/JConsole.png

Comment: Thats weird - now it looks fine. Have no idea why.

Comment: I also just tried to set up a basic test and it worked with two different settings. The only bug I know of is that the validation options are not properly separated between sessions when the same data dictionary is used. All other things should be fine when specified differently for separate sessions.

Comment: It appears so. Thank you for your help.